# Why the following code with non-const conversion function is not ambiguous?

Tags: c++, c++11, type-conversion, operators

Consider the following code (taken from https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/cast_operator)

```
struct To {
    To() = default;
    To(const struct From&) {} // converting constructor
};

struct From {
    operator To() const {return To();} // conversion function
};

int main()
{
    From f;

    To t2 = f; // copy-initialization: ambiguous
// (note, if conversion function is from a non-const type, e.g.
//  From::operator To();, it will be selected instead of the ctor in this case)
}
```

As the comments say, the following line is indeed ambiguous because there are two candidates (The conversion function and the converting constructor are equally applicable)

```
To t2 = f; //compile error
```

However, as the note says if I remove the `const` from the `conversion` function resulting in the following code:

```
struct From {
    operator To() {return To();} // conversion function
};
```

The call compiles fine.
The `const` qualifier should not affect the `conversion` function return value, so why the call is no longer ambiguous?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The const qualifier should not affect the conversion function return value

It doesn't affect that indeed, but that's also not relevant.

What it does affect is the argument - which is the implicit reference to `this`. The implicit argument is a const lvalue for const member functions and non-const for non-const member functions. The arguments are what affect the overload resolution.

In the original code, both the constructor and the conversion operator arguments are exactly the same, so a conversion sequence from any type to either argument is equally preferable, and therefore ambiguous.

Without the const, your non-const lvalue  expression `f` doesn't need any conversions, while the constructor does require a conversion into const lvalue. As such, the operator is preferred by the overload resolution. If you had written `const From f;`, then the constructor whose argument is const would have been chosen instead as in that case, the non-const conversion operator wouldn't even be valid candidate.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning the implicit parameter, that made it clear! Maybe you meant this as a pointer not a reference. (But the answer holds true anyway, &f which is int* gets implicitly passed, in the non-cost version this is also an int* and being an exact match wins over the constructor)

Comment: @A.S. `this` keyword is a pointer, but the implicit argument is a reference.

Comment: @A.S. also, if you do things like `std::invoke`, it's a reference there as well. Unless I'm missing something, the only reason why `this` is a pointer is because member functions were introduced to the language before references.

Comment: The standard indeed states it is has reference type with the same cv qualifiers as the method. Thanks, I didn’t know about this.

Answer (score 3):

> The const qualifier should not affect the conversion function return value, so why the call is no longer ambiguous?

It does not affect the result, but it affects overload resolution for choosing the best viable method. It's similar to the case of these made up functions

```
To make(From const&);
To make(From&);
```

Which overload is the better match in `make(f)`? It's the second one, because the parameter type, being non-const, better matches the argument (`f`), which is non-const itself.